# Property id does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel

I want to add the Interest_status key on my response. But shows me error. Here is my code. Please Help. Thanks in advance.

```
    $activities_status = [];

    $activities = [];

    foreach ($activitiesDetail as $activityDetail) { 

        $activity = '';

        if(in_array($activityDetail->user_id, $userFriendIds))

        {

            $activity = Activity::where('id', $activityDetail->id)->with('joins')->get();


        } 

        else {

            $activity = Activity::where('id', $activityDetail->id)
                ->where('activity_privacy_visible', 0)->with('joins')->get();

        }

        $interest = $authUser->interests()->where('activity_id', $activity->id)->first();


            if($interest)

            {

                $status['interest_status'] = $interest->status;

                $activities_status[] = array_merge($status, $activity->toArray());


            } else {

                $status['interest_status'] = NULL;

                $activities_status[] = array_merge($status, $activity->toArray());


            }

        $activities = array_merge($activities, $activities_status);
    }
    return response()->json(['filter'=> $activities], 200);
```

If I print the Interest_status it gives me the value of status but I return the whole response it shows error.Please Help.

Comment: What are you getting in ```$activities``` array? Do you have ```interest_status``` in ```$activities``` array?

Comment: No i have not Interest_status in activities array

Comment: I see no reason that ```interest_status``` in ```$activities``` array. Just check if you are overwriting values in code.

Comment: i add this key that show the status of interest on activity to app side so please help and resolve my issue @pra